# How to make clang-check to generate html reports?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-static-analyzer

I am running clang-check 5.0 on centos 7.5 to run the static analysis. How can I set clang-check to generate html reports? Plist files can be generated fine.

Here's the command I have used, but it does not work. No html file is generated. Thanks.

```
clang-check -analyze -p compile_commands.json -extra-arg=-Xanalyzer -extra-arg=-analyzer-output=html -extra-arg=-o=html_output xxx.cpp

warning: could not create file in 'xxx.plist': Not a directory
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command-line arguments are correct to make clang-check generate HTML reports. However, the ClangTool frontend will filter out the `-o` arguments no matter it is captured from the compilation database or added in command-line arguments. And the value of `-o` argument will be replaced as `xxx.plist` in your case.

If `xxx.plist` is an existing file, you need to remove it first. And clang-check will automatically create a folder named `xxx.plist` with all HTML reports for file `xxx.cpp` generated inside.

There is no way to override the default `-o` argument currently. Fortunately, with [my patch](https://reviews.llvm.org/rGda168dd875bf0392e8e88834009d776bfbaae376), it will be available in clang-check 14 via argument `-analyzer-output-path`.